# ¿Como añadir fuentes y javadoc de una libreria externa con gradle e IntelliJ?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, javadoc

Tengo un proyecto en Java que estoy desarrollando con IntelliJ y Gradle. He definido el bloque **idea** en mi `build.gradle` que, en resumidas cuentas, lo que hace es descargar los fuentes y javadoc de aquéllas librerias que se encuentran en algún repositorio maven:

```
idea{
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true // defaults to false
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
```

Hasta aquí todo correcto. Sin embargo, tengo una librería externa, la cual no se encuentra en ningún repositorio maven. Para importar esta librería he definido, en el bloque **repositories** la carpeta libs, en la que he dejado caer la libreria y su correspondiente javadoc.

```
repositories {
    // repositorios maven
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

He añadido las dependencias correspondientes en el bloque **dependencies**. El proyecto compila correctamente y carga los javadoc de aquellas librerias que se descargan de un repositorio maven, sin embargo no carga el javadoc de la librería externa en cuestión. ¿Tengo que definir de algún  modo los javadoc de dicha librería en mi build.gradle?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece ser que el problema reside en la estructura de directorios y ficheros del fichero javadoc. Tras analizar el jar de javadoc, parece ser que no disponía la estructura de ficheros adecuada. Al abrir el jar (con 7zip), éste contiene un directorio llamado ***javadoc*** el cual contiene los directorios y ficheros de la documentación.

La solución pasa, simplemente, por eliminar dicho directorio intermedio, dejando los ficheros y directorios que éste contenía en la raíz del jar.